# Compare row by value in SQL Server Select Command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I write a select query

```
select COUNT(csq.PK) as 'QuestionCount' , csq.VersionID     
        from tversion as aiv 
        inner join tquestion as csq csq.VersionID=aiv.VersionID     
        group by csq.VersionID
```

which returns bellow table.

[image]

I want to check if QuestionCount mismatch in any row .

How I do the checking within the select Query?

Comment: What's the expected result here?

Comment: Here QuestionCount is Different ,so I need a indication may be True or False .

Comment: Different from what? Please post your expected result in the question.

Comment: If all 4 rows contains same QuestionCount then I need an Indication line 'No Mismatch' and if any has different value then 'Mismatched'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    with cte as
    (
    select COUNT(csq.PK) as QuestionCount , csq.VersionID     
    from tversion as aiv 
    inner join tquestion as csq csq.VersionID=aiv.VersionID     
    group by csq.VersionID
    )
    select case count(distinct QuestionCount)
                when 1 then 'No Mismatch'
                else 'Mismatched'
           end as result
    from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(csq.PK) AS 'QuestionCount'
FROM tversion AS aiv
INNER JOIN tquestion AS csq ON csq.VersionID = aiv.VersionID
GROUP BY csq.VersionID

SELECT CASE @@ROWCOUNT WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
```

Another way:

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(csq.PK) AS 'QuestionCount'
    FROM tversion AS aiv
    INNER JOIN tquestion AS csq ON csq.VersionID = aiv.VersionID
    GROUP BY csq.VersionID
) AS T
```

Comment: Not working ,I want to check value of QuestionCount from each row ,not count .

Comment: @KuntalBose, it doesn't just `COUNT`, it does `DISTINCT COUNT` then compares against `WHEN 1`. If you did try it, please specify its output against expected output. Also, a little [`CREATE TABLE; INSERT INTO;`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) script might be helpful.